# Cannot find function via Rserve but it is visible in R

Tags: java, r, rserve

I am trying the Java client to rserve.  I have a function defined in R as follows:

```
bar <- function(x) { x+1 }
```

executing this inside R gives the following (expected) output:

```
> bar(1)
[1] 2
```

however, executing the following Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws REXPMismatchException, REngineException {
  RConnection c = new RConnection();
  REXP x = c.eval("try({bar(1)}, silent=TRUE)");
  System.out.println(x.asString());

}
```

gives the following output:

```
Error in try({ : could not find function "bar"
```

inside the R console the following message is output:

```
> Error: could not find function "bar"
```

Is there something I need to do to make my function visible to Rserve?

Steve

Answer (score 0):

You are defining your function inside of a different workspace / process. Rserve and R do not share the same process space so declaring your method in one will not make it appear in Rserve workspace.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws REXPMismatchException, REngineException {
  RConnection c = new RConnection();
  REXP x = c.eval("try({bar <- function(x) { x+1 }; bar(1)}, silent=TRUE)");
  System.out.println(x.asString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i had similar issue, you need to store your R code in a file which is called when Rserve is started (within same process), steps to be taken:

1. Create file with your R code (functions etc. ...) and name it for example **filename.R**
2. Create **Rserv.conf** file and paste there line

   source /path to the file with R code/filename.R
3. Run R serve using command

   Rserve(debug = TRUE, args='--no-save --RS-conf /path to the Rserv file/Rserv.conf')

it should works ...